# ToggleOut on blur?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a menu that gets toggled and want it to toggle out on blur. Currently it only toggles out on click of the toggle button.  How is it possible to also toggle out when you blur out of the menu?  I've tried 2 ways, which don't seem to work.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q6b7jtw7/

Html:

```
<button class="one">Toggle 1</button>
<ul class="one">
    <li>1</li>
</ul>

<button class="two">Toggle 2</button>
<ul class="two">
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("button.one").click(function(){
  $("ul.one").slideToggle();
  $("body")
    .not("ul.one")
    .not("button.one")
    .one("click",function(){$("ul.one").slideToggle();});
});


$("button.two").click(function(){
    $("ul.two").slideToggle().focus().blur(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle();
    });    
});
```

Comment: How can you blur a menu?

Comment: @Shomz The first example doesn't work either though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to trigger the **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events.
The **onblur** event is fired when an input lose focus, and you don't have any input in your html.

**UPDATED**

Now you can open and close the menu with the button, and also hide it when you're leaving the menu.

```
    $("button.three").click(function(){
       $("#menu3").find('li:not(:first-child)').slideToggle();   
    });

    $("#menu3")
     .on( "mouseleave", function() {
        var menuLi = $(this).find('li:not(:first-child)');
         if(menuLi.is(':visible')){
              menuLi.slideToggle();
         }
     });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/q6b7jtw7/9/) the full working example.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is fired on hover. I need it on click of the toggle button. Please view the example for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("#menu3").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('li:not(:first-child)').slideToggle();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n34oqrj/)